# changenr() + undo does not work as expected

Tags: undo-redo

Minimal (not-)working example:

```
fun! Test()
  let save=changenr()
  call append(0, "THIS MUST BE UNDONE")
  exe "undo ".save
endfun
command! -nargs=0 T :call Test()
```

Now open a file, insert some garbage (because "undo 0" won't work), then call the command `:T` three times in a row.

On my machine at least, the first two times it works as expected (i.e. does nothing). But the last time the text `THIS MUST BE UNDONE` is added to the buffer. On closer inspection, the value of `save` used on the third execution is 2, while the two previous ones were both 1.

What happened? (Probably something mysterious related to `undotree`)?

**edit**: while I'm at it, the fact that `undo 0` does not work looks like a bug in itself. If I open a file and then do two modifications A and B, then `undo 1` puts me after A, `undo 2` puts me after A+B, but vim refuses to `undo 0` to put me before A...

Comment: What are you trying to do? [(XY Problem)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/188334)

Comment: @Circonflexe The problem comes from the function `changenr()` which sometimes returns a value that you (and I) don't understand. Most of the time, it returns what you (and I) expect, but sometimes (when you go back to the root), instead of returning the change number of the current leaf, it returns the change number of the deepest leaf in the nearest "inactive branch".

Comment: @Circonflexe Because of this, sometimes your `save` variable contains a value which is too high, therefore your `exe "undo " . save` doesn't bring you back to the expected leaf and your text `this must be undone` is not removed.

Comment: @mMontu: This is a MWE, strictly about `undo`. The full function would be a `:w` filter (make changes, save file, undo changes).

@saginaw, also @mMontu's answer below: so far nothing new, I did write all those `echo` lines in my function,  (again **M**WE...)

Comment: @Circonflexe I don't know how to do it, but you need to find a way to get the id of the current leaf / node, and `changenr()` is not a reliable way to get this info, because when you undo, it doesn't return the current id, it returns this: `After undo it is one less than the number of the undone change.` Maybe this link will help you a little: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/dszuz/gundo_my_little_undo_tree_visualization_plugin/c12ril4 What this person says is that you must look in the dictionary returned by `undotree()`.

Comment: @Circonflexe If no node in the tree is marked with the key `curhead`, then it means you can use `changenr()` to get the id of the current node. But if there's one node which is marked with `curhead`, then your current node is its parent (not `changenr()`). So, unless someone else has a simpler way of doing it, the first step would be to find how to parse the undo tree, that is the dictionary returned by `undotree()` to find if a node is marked with `curhead`. The output of `undotree()` is quite complex, it seems to be a recursive imbrication of dictionaries and lists.

Comment: @Circonflexe However, once you have found how to parse this (again I don't know how), then your problem should be quite easy to solve. You could look at how other people have solved the parsing problem, here for example: https://github.com/mbbill/undotree/blob/39e5cf0fc241c64e920f91d52299b444475d54df/plugin/undotree.vim#L783-L809

Comment: @Circonflexe `The full function would be a :w filter (make changes, save file, undo changes)` -- this still seems as the Y problem in the XY problem. For instance, if your X problem is to write an adapted version of the current buffer to a different file, it could be easier to forget about the undo feature and just copy the current buffer to a new temporary buffer, where you filter and save the contents, them just discard the buffer instead of poluting and fighting the undo tree.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to learn how the undotree feature works, [similar to this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/), then you should use some plugin to have a graphic representation of the undotree while you try the commands.

It is also useful to increase the verbosity of your test function:

```
fun! Test()
  echom 'prev changenr() = '.changenr()
  let save=changenr()
  call append(0, "THIS MUST BE UNDONE")
  exe "undo ".save
  echom 'post changenr() = '.changenr()
endfun
command! -nargs=0 T :call Test()
```

For your test case, I noticed that each execution of the `:T` command inserts a node on the undotree. Before starting the test the [undo tree plugin](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree/) shows the following:

```
 *   >2<   (1 second ago)
 *    1    (2 seconds ago)
 *    0    (Original)
```

First execution of `:T`

```
prev changenr() = 2
1 line less; after #2  20 seconds ago
post changenr() = 2


 *   {3}   (1 second ago)
 *   >2<   (21 seconds ago)
 *    1    (22 seconds ago)
 *    0    (Original)
```

After the second `:T`:

```
prev changenr() = 2
1 line less; after #2  31 seconds ago
post changenr() = 3


 *   {4}   (1 second ago)
 | *    3    (12 seconds ago)
 |/
 *   >2<   (32 seconds ago)
 *    1    (33 seconds ago)
 *    0    (Original)
```

Note the `line less` messages -- the command `:T` changed the buffer, thus it changed the undotree.

It is possible that the creation of the branch when change `{4}` is introduced caused `changenr()` to return the different value.